# Getting null pointer exception while calling EJB method from junit

Tags: junit, ejb

I am writing unit Junit test case for entity java bean.But, when i call the EJB method i am getting an null pointer exception the code is like below

UserServiceTest.java

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")
    private EntityManager em;    

    private static UserService userService;


    @Test
    public void registerUser() {
        userService = new UserService();
        resultData = userService.registerUser(name, email, password, mobileNumber, countryId);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, resultData.isSet);
        Assert.assertEquals(message, resultData.message);

    }
```

UserService.java

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")
    private EntityManager em;
public ResultData registerUser(String name, String email, String password, String mobileNumber, String countryId) {    

        try {   

            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByEmail", User.class).setParameter("email", email);
            users = q.getResultList();
            if (!users.isEmpty()) {
                userDataClass.isSet = false;
                userDataClass.message = "A user with this email already exists.";

                return userDataClass;
            }catch (Exception e) {
            userDataClass.isSet = false;

        }
```

The above code i debugged. When the ponter came to entityManager

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByEmail", User.class).setParameter("email", email);
```

I am getting an null pointer exception.

Can any one plz help me

Comment: In your unit tests, there is no EJB container to inject anything, and you're not passing any EntityManager to the service when constructing it. So yes, obviously, the entityManager is null. You'll have to create an EntityManager explicitely, as you would do in a Java SE application, and pass it to your service. Or use a test framework like Arquillian.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I tried to create an entity manager like below ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();ctx = ejbContainer.getContext(); but, i am getting an javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to deploy EJB modules